# Stop all ads from Heyzap SDK for In App Purchase "Remove Ads"

Tags: ios, objective-c, heyzap

I'm trying to stop all ads after an In App Purchase on iOS using the Heyzap SDK.

I've tried:

```
-(void) OnRemoveADS {
  ...

 [self buyFeatureRemoveADS];

 [HeyzapAds nil];
 [HeyzapAds removeFromSuperview];
  HZInterstitialAd = nil;
}
```

And they all produce Xcode errors.

I know I'm going to have to turn them off from different spots because my banner ads are initialized separately from the interstitials.

Like in the else statement in this method:

```
-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    g_bRemoveADS=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"REMOVEADS"];

    if(!g_bRemoveADS)
    {

       [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] view];

        HZBannerAdOptions *options = [[HZBannerAdOptions alloc] init];
        //options.presentingViewController = self;

        [HZBannerAd placeBannerInView:self.view
                             position:HZBannerPositionBottom
                              options:options
                              success:^(HZBannerAd *banner) {
                                  NSLog(@"Ad Shown!");

                              } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
                              }];
    }

    else {

        // Stop banner ads here

    }
```

In the MKStoreManger, there are methods for removing ads:

```
- (void) buyFeatureRemoveADs {
   [self buyFeature:featureRemoveADSId];
}
```

A static string:

```
  static NSString *featureRemoveADSId = IAP_RemoveADS;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an iOS engineer at Heyzap.

Not showing interstitial, video, or incentivized ads when ads are disabled is very easy: just check the `g_bRemoveADS` `BOOL` value before showing them:

```
g_bRemoveADS = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"REMOVEADS"];

// For HZInterstitialAd, HZVideoAd, and HZIncentivizedAd, just check the BOOL to see if an ad should be shown
if (!g_bRemoveADS) {
    [HZInterstitialAd show];
}
```

For HZBannerAd, there are three cases to consider:

1. We haven't fetched a banner yet, in which case don't bother fetching if ads are disabled.
2. The banner is still being requested and we're waiting for it to be fetched. Destroy the banner in success block.
3. The banner is already on screen, in which case we should remove it when ads are disabled.

Here's the code for banners:

```
if (!g_bRemoveADS) { // case (1)
    [HZBannerAd placeBannerInView:self.view
                         position:HZBannerPositionBottom
                          options:options
                          success:^(HZBannerAd *banner) {
                              if (g_bRemoveADS) { // case (2)
                                  // Just discard the banner
                                  [banner removeFromSuperview];
                              } else {
                                  // Keep a reference to the current banner ad, so we can remove it from screen later if we want to disable ads.
                                  self.currentBannerAd = banner;
                              }
                              NSLog(@"Ad Shown!");

                          } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
                          }];
}
```

I made a separate `disableAds` method that sets the value in `NSUserDefaults` and destroys the current banner, if there is one.

```
- (void)disableAds {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"REMOVEADS"];
    [currentBannerAd removeFromSuperview]; // case (3)
}
```

The current `HZBannerAd` interface is somewhat complex. We're working on a simpler interface that would make handle all of that complexity for you.

Comment: I got it to work to get rid of interstitials, but the banner ads remain. I'm getting an Xcode error from `currentBannerAd`. Should I make a property out of it. If so, how? A UIView?

Comment: I tried putting in a property `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView  *currentBannerAd;`  Still not removing the banners.

Comment: @Paul can you put the code you're using in a gist or paste it somewhere, or update your original question with your new code?

Comment: OK, I'll make a gist.

Comment: @Paul that code looks correct to me. Are you calling the `disableAds` method (maybe add some logging to make sure that's called?)

Comment: Check the gist again. I slightly modified it and added a log statement. The log is called, but the banners still remain. No change from calling `disableAds`. Is the property I set up for `currentBannerAd` correct in the `GameOverScene.h`?

Comment: I can send you a link to the full app if you'd like?

Comment: @Paul I think it would work if you always did `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"REMOVEADS"]` instead of saving that to a variable. Alternatively, you should update the `g_bRemoveADS` every time you update the value in `NSUserDefaults`. A full link to the app would be helpful if you can provide that.

Comment: Let me know when you download it.

Comment: Here's a link to the app:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ewa5sdow7huz53c/AAAjDTiKuAfc2lMKVlemQQzua?dl=0

Comment: Did you download the project yet?

Comment: @MaxGabriel, I've read around this site that using NSUserDefaults is not secure and easy to hack. There are software out there that would allow users to modify NSUserdefaults

Comment: @joeygusto That appears to be correct. You may want to use an alternate storage then.